# Error : Undefined property: Account::$Account_model

Tags: php

A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Account::$Account_model

Filename: Admin/Account.php

Line Number: 19

Backtrace:

```
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\AdminLTE\application\controllers\Admin\Account.php
Line: 19
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\AdminLTE\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

```php
class Account extends CI_Controller {

    public function _construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Account_model');
    }


    public function index() {

        $mdat=[
            'active_controller' => 'master',
            'active_function' => 'account/account_view',
        ];

        $this->load->view('admin/global/menu', $mdat);

        $data['books']=$this->Account_model->get_all_acc();
        $this->load->view('account_view',$data);
    }

this is my model :
class Account_model extends CI_Model
{
    var $table = 'books';

    public function acc_add($data) {

        $this->db->insert($this->table,$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function get_all_acc() {
        $this->db->from('books');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: The `_construct()` method requires two underscore to be called as magic method. Worth trying to debug the code and follow it to see if the line that is loading the model is executed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your function construct to this one :

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Account_model');
}
```

because the construct function require double underscore and you just typing one underscore

Comment: i changed to single underscore, but same error in line 19         $data['books']=$this->Account_model->get_all_acc();

Comment: have you tried to change it into double underscore at the function construct?

Comment: change your `_construct` into `__construct`

Comment: Thanks, i tried change back to double underscode, now it solved

Comment: my control code :         $data['books']=$this->Account_model->get_all_acc();
        $this->load->view('account_view',$data); and my view code :                           <?php
 foreach($books as $book) {?>